# Develop a Naïve Bayesian classifier as an email filter in Python without Machine Learning Library

Tags: python, naivebayes

Dataset I have is ("wordsList.csv" and "classList.csv")

wordsList file contains 72 pre-processed emails. Each line is a list of words extracted from each email.

The classList file contains the class labels that indicating whether the emails are ordinary or adverts (0 for ordinary and 1 for adverts).

My task is to develop a Naïve Bayesian classifier as an email filter in Python. Namely, the classifier predicts whether emails are ordinary or adverts.

The Naïve Bayesian classifier must account for multiple occurrences of words and implements techniques to overcome the numerical underflows and zero counts.

But the bad news is that I can't use any machine learning library, only sciPy and NumPy are allowed, is there any way to implement this? And if so is there any sample code that implements this method from scratch? Thank you in advance!

[image: wordsList table]
[image: classList table]

Comment: @BlackBear let's assume good faith on the part of such askers. You might suspect they are cheating on an assignment, but perhaps they are not. William, you might look at SKLearn's implementations. If you sit through a lecture on the implementation of these algorithms, you might find you can do it yourself. It's been a long time since I've sat through such a lecture, and I really don't have the time, so I don't think I'll make an attempt at an answer today. I suggest you make an attempt and if you hit a roadblock, revise your question, and show your work, and you might turn it around.

Comment: alright will do! Thanks for a good suggestion @AaronHall

Comment: And if I do need to cheat on assignment, I might as well pay someone to do it for me right? Why should I type here?

Comment: It's free here :p Sorry I was too harsh yesterday. Try to come up with something on your own first, then we will definitely help you if it still does not work